# unable to create database in mysql or via ssh

Tags: mysql

I m trying to create new database through **mysql or ssh** but on both m getting error

```
mysql : CREATE DATABASE porto;
```

> Error : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'porto' on ssh : ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'porto'

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ecomaddon@42';
```

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host From mysql.user;
```

> ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'

Its problem of privilege but don't know how give root user all privilege ai had try all methods but got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to access as root

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

---

If it still does not work follow this guide
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/managing-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line

Comment: getting error after connect mysql 

mysql> CREATE DATABASE porto;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'porto'

Comment: Try to check the root@localhost privileges on your phpmyadmin

Comment: i understand its privilege problem but don't know how to grant it for all . its not working there. m trying to create new user but still not working.

Comment: i have access i was trying to create a new database from mysql side but still same access denied error

Comment: Try to read this article https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/managing-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line and tell me if works for you

Comment: Thanks for  help bro . this link helps me alot

Answer (score 0):

you may be login as root but the root@localhost is not allowed for the actions you are executing.

```
mysql>CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'enter_your_password_here';
mysql>exit
```

then try logging-in again

Comment: mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nothing@aa';

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: grant all privileges on*.*to 'root'@'localhost'; (please add space after "on" and before "to")

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: how i wish i can see the result of this: SELECT User, Host, authentication_string FROM mysql.user;

Comment: its still display denied error when m trying to select query

Answer (score 0):

I think it's rights issue & It can be resolved by re configuring again. Here's a steps to reconfigure it.

1. Stop the current MySQL server instance:
   sudo service mysql stop
2. Use dpkg to re-run the configuration process that MySQL goes through on first installation. You will again be asked to set a root password.
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5

Comment: i m not able to getting 2 step . please can u explain me easy way.

Comment: Are you using windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: First check your package name using sudo apt list --installed & then find out a mysql-server package. Using this package name run sudo dpkg-reconfigure package_name command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply to all 
i had solve i 
1. first  login to new user.
2. give access all to that users by update command . 
3. drop root user and rename second user to root.
main problem was :  when we create root it didn't give grant_priv field access users .